# Which GTA Online cars can you steal and own?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

Does anyone know which cars can be made your "personal car" by stealing? Or which ones can't?

Out of them, is there a "best" non-purchased car in terms of speed/acceleration/the usual?

EDIT: I'm making a list over here, feel free to contribute: [Which stolen cars can you bring to LS Customs and what are their sell prices in GTA Online?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/133145/gta-online-which-stolen-cars-can-you-bring-to-ls-customs-corollary-has-anyon)

Comment: As far as I know you cannot go to a Los Santos Customs to modify super sports cars, because they are considers "too hot" and the game asks you to buy them off of the ingame websites. I don't know if you can put them in a garage and make them yours that way. Also I don't know if they are still considered "too hot" if you manage to put them in a garage you own. So yeah... too much "if" to make this an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can still upgrade the Sports cars like the Inferno, Banshee, etc. However, you can not upgrade them if you stole it. By LS Customs telling you the car is "too hot" it means that it's a Super Sports care that was stolen. To upgrade one of the vehicles, you have to actually spend your money on the web and purchase them. No worries though, buy insurance and a tracker for them and you will always be able to get your vehicle back even if it blows up.

Comment: I've done it with some other high end cars that aren't in the super sport category though, and they can't be upgraded either.

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone know which cars can be made your "personal car" by stealing? Or which ones can't?

There is a list of cars that fit this category in this GTA wiki article: [Los Santos Customs/Vehicle Prices](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Los_Santos_Customs/Vehicle_Prices) and in the answers to the Arqade question: [Which stolen cars can you bring to LS Customs and what are their sell prices in GTA Online?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/133145/gta-online-which-stolen-cars-can-you-bring-to-ls-customs-corollary-has-anyon)

> Out of them, is there a "best" non purchased car in terms of speed/acceleration/the usual?

According to [Broughy1322](https://gtacars.net/gta5/tiers), who [tests vehicle top speed](https://gtacars.net/gta5/topspeed) by driving them on a road (as opposed to just getting the speed stat in the game files), the current fastest vehicle that can be made a personal vehicle by stealing is the [**Pegassi Ruffian**](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Ruffian) (a motorcycle), with the [Vapid Dominator](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Dominator) second, and the [Maibatsu Sanchez](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Sanchez) (a motorcycle) third. Among cars, the **[Vapid Dominator](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Dominator)** is the fastest with the [Karin Futo](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Futo) coming in second.

Putting the stats of those vehicles here for better comparison:

|  | Pegassi Ruffian | Vapid Dominator | Maibatsu Sanchez | Karin Futo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Top Speed - Real (Broughy) | 127.00 mph (204.39 km/h) | 120.25 mph (193.52 km/h) | 119.50 mph (192.32 km/h) | 119.25 mph (191.91 km/h) |
| Lap Time (Broughy) (m:ss.000) | 1:02.461 | 1:09.035 | 1:04.532 | 1:12.706 |
| Top Speed (Game Files) | 86.99 mph (140.00 km/h) | 90.10 mph (145.00 km/h) | 73.32 mph (118.00 km/h) | 83.89 mph (135.00 km/h) |
| Price | $10,000 | $35,000 | $8,000 | $9,000 |
| Mass/Weight | 250 KG | 1,600 KG | 220 KG | 900 KG |

Sources:

- [Broughy1322 - GTA 5 Vehicle Info, Performance & Tier Lists](https://gtacars.net/gta5/tiers)
- [Broughy1322's top speed testing methodology](https://gtacars.net/gta5/topspeed)
- [Broughy1322's lap time testing methodology](https://gtacars.net/gta5/laptime)
- [GTABase.com GTA V Vehicle Database](https://www.gtabase.com/grand-theft-auto-v/vehicles/#sort=attr.ct132.frontend_value&sortdir=desc&attr.ct12.value=stealable&page=1)