# Which stolen cars can you bring to LS Customs and what are their sell prices in GTA Online?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

Note that these cars would also be outfitable with a tracker and insurance, and therefore useable as a personal car without having to buy.

Comment: I know the hummer/Patriot goes for $5000, and one of the Range Rovers goes for $7000, not the "balla" one, if anybody decides to make a list.

Comment: 3100 for the bravado gauntlet

Comment: I'm seeing a *lot* of proposed edits on this question's answers. Is this going to be an Unmaintainable List Question? If so, it's not on-topic.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I think it's more because it's asking for a big list and we don't know all the information about it yet. Having a CW answer is good, but it was made CW too late to catch the other posts in it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A list of at least some of the cars with prices:

- Lampadati Felon GT(coupe) - **$9500**
- Gallivanter Baller(SUV) - **$9000**
- Lampadati Felon(coupe) - **$9000**
- Ocelot F620(coupe) - **$8000**
- Ubermacht Oracle(sedan) - **$8000**
- Albany Cavalcade(SUV) - **$7000**
- Benefactor Dubsta(SUV) - **$7000**
- Ubermacht Zion Cabria(coupe/cab) - **$6500**
- Ubermacht Sentinel xs(coupe) - **$6000**
- Ocelot Jackal(sedan) - **$6000**
- Benefactor Serrano(SUV) - **$6000**
- Mammoth Patriot(SUV) - **$5000**
- Dundreary Landstalker(SUV) - **$5000**
- Fantom FQ(Suv) - **$5000**
- Cheval Surge(sedan) - **$3800**
- Schyster Fusilade(coupe) - **$3600**
- Dundrey Granger(SUV) - **$3500**
- Vapid Dominator(coupe) - **$3500**
- Bravado Buffalo(sedan) - **$3500**
- Vapid Radius(Suv) - **$3200**
- Bravado Gauntlet(coupe) - **$3100**
- Canis Seminole(SUV) - **$3000**
- Declasse Tornado(coupe) - **$3000**
- Bravado Gresley(SUV) - **$2900**
- Karin Asterope(sedan) - **$2500**
- Maibatsu Penumbra(coupe) - **$2400**
- Imponte Phoenix(sedan) - **$2000**
- Weeny Issi(mini) - **$1800**
- Albany Washington(sedan) - **$1500**
- Ziconium Stratum(wagon) - **$1000**
- Albany Empreor(sedan) - **$800**

This is probably not all, but something :) (I will keep update the list as I find moore)

Comment: there's also this, someone did most of the dirty work https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AvMnvlv4JzeKdGRVQlVHVUlRY2VoZGQtaFBGYW1HVlE&usp=sharing#gid=0

Answer (score 7):

Alright, until someone else comes out in the clutch, I'm going to start figuring it out myself. If anyone wants to comment with their findings, that'd be cool.

- Mammoth Patriot **$5000**
- Bravado Gauntlet **$3100**
- Benefactor Dubsta **$71??**
- Vapid Dominator **$3500**
- Ocelotte F620 **$8000**
- Ubermacht Zion Cabrio (Coupe) **$6500**
- Fathom FQ (SUV) **$5000**
- Vapid Radius (SUV) **$3200**
- Gallivanter Ballar (SUV) **$9000**
- Ubermacht Sentinel **$6000**

Comment: I suggest you make your post Community Wiki so anybody can edit it with information they've found. :)

Comment: @Schism How do I do that?

Comment: For you and you alone, as the answer author, between the edit window and the preview screen, there's a checkbox that says "community wiki" on the right hand side.

Answer (score 3):

You can check in game for the available cars for the ls customs. Anything listed in Legendary Motor sport is considered "hot item"  and can't be sold in LS customs. All the cars in Southern Sanandreas Super Auto can be sold for 10% of the listed price.

Comment: If this is true it might be the best answer, or at least lead to a full list easily. I'm gonna check it out

Answer (score 3):

The best cars I have found to sell are the [Gallivanter Baller](http://gta.wikia.com/Baller) and the [Gallivanter Baller 2](http://gta.wikia.com/Baller_%28Version_II%29) that both sell for around $9000 dollars a pop in pristine condition with no mods.

Also, you can only sell 1 car per in-game day, which works out at around 48 real minutes.

Answer (score 1):

> The prices listed here are for vehicles which arrive in mint
> condition. If the vehicle has been damaged, the value will reduce by
> the same amount that it will cost to repair the vehicle. Thus, when
> going to sell a vehicle to Los Santos Customs, the player will receive
> the same profit whether they repair the vehicle or not.

Source: [**Los Santos Customs/Vehicle Prices** - GTA Wiki](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Los_Santos_Customs/Vehicle_Prices) (updated 2022-06-04)

| Make | Model | Selling Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [Lampadati](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Lampadati) | [Felon GT](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Felon_GT) | $9,500 |
| [Übermacht](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/%C3%9Cbermacht) | [Sentinel](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Sentinel) | $9,500 |
| [Gallivanter](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Gallivanter) | [Baller](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Baller) | $9,000 |
| [Lampadati](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Lampadati) | [Felon](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Felon) | $9,000 |
| [Canis](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Canis) | [Mesa (Merryweather)](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Merryweather_Mesa) | $8,500 (Unsellable as of 1.10) |
| [Obey](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Obey) | [Rocoto](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Rocoto) | $8,500 |
| [Übermacht](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/%C3%9Cbermacht) | [Oracle XS](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Oracle_XS) | $8,200 (as of the [Heists Update](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Heists_Update)) |
| [Übermacht](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/%C3%9Cbermacht) | [Oracle](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Oracle) | $8,000 |
| [Benefactor](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Benefactor) | [Schwartzer](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Schwartzer) | $8,000 |
| [Ocelot](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Ocelot) | [F620](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/F620) | $8,000 |
| [Albany](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Albany) | [Cavalcade](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Cavalcade) | $7,000 |
| [Benefactor](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Benefactor) | [Dubsta](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Dubsta) | $7,000 |
| [Benefactor](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Benefactor) | [Schafter](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Schafter) | $6,500 |
| [Übermacht](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/%C3%9Cbermacht) | [Zion Cabrio](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Zion_Cabrio) | $6,500 |
| [Übermacht](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/%C3%9Cbermacht) | [Zion](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Zion) | $6,200 |
| [Benefactor](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Benefactor) | [Serrano](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Serrano) | $6,000 |
| [Ocelot](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Ocelot) | [Jackal](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Jackal) | $6,000 |
| [Übermacht](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/%C3%9Cbermacht) | [Sentinel XS](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Sentinel_XS) | $6,000 |
| [Dundreary](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Dundreary) | [Landstalker](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Landstalker) | $5,800 |
| [Obey](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Obey) | [Tailgater](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Tailgater) | $5,500 |
| [Fathom](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Fathom) | [FQ 2](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/FQ_2) | $5,000 |
| [Mammoth](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Mammoth) | [Patriot](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Patriot) | $5,000 |
| [Chariot](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Chariot) | [Romero Hearse](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Romero_Hearse) | $4,500 |
| [Vapid](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Vapid) | [Sandking SWB](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Sandking_SWB) | $4,500 |
| [Vapid](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Vapid) | [Sandking XL](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Sandking_XL) | $4,500 |
| [Emperor](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Emperor) | [Habanero](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Habanero) | $4,200 |
| [Cheval](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Cheval) | [Surge](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Surge) | $3,800 |
| [Schyster](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Schyster) | [Fusilade](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Fusilade) | $3,600 |
| [Bravado](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Bravado) | [Buffalo](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Buffalo) | $3,500 |
| [Declasse](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Declasse) | [Granger](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Granger) | $3,500 |
| [Vapid](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Vapid) | [Dominator](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Dominator) | $3,500 |
| [Vapid](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Vapid) | [Sadler](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Sadler) | $3,500 |
| [Bravado](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Bravado) | [Gauntlet](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Gauntlet) | $3,200 |
| [Vapid](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Vapid) | [Radius](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Radius) | $3,200 |
| [Bravado](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Bravado) | [Bison](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Bison) | $3,000 |
| [Canis](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Canis) | [Mesa](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Mesa) | $3,000 |
| [Canis](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Canis) | [Seminole](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Seminole) | $3,000 |
| [Declasse](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Declasse) | [Tornado](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Tornado) | $3,000 |
| [Vapid](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Vapid) | [Minivan](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Minivan) | $3,000 |
| [Bravado](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Bravado) | [Gresley](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Gresley) | $2,900 |
| [Albany](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Albany) | [Buccaneer](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Buccaneer) | $2,800 |
| [Karin](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Karin) | [BeeJay XL](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/BeeJay_XL) | $2,700 |
| [Karin](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Karin) | [Asterope](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Asterope) | $2,600 |
| [Bollokan](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Bollokan) | [Prairie](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Prairie) | $2,500 |
| [Karin](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Karin) | [Dilettante](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Dilettante) | $2,500 |
| [Cheval](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Cheval) | [Fugitive](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Fugitive) | $2,400 |
| [Maibatsu](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Maibatsu) | [Penumbra](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Penumbra) | $2,400 |
| [Vapid](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Vapid) | [Bobcat XL](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Bobcat_XL) | $2,300 |
| [Declasse](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Declasse) | [Vigero](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Vigero) | $2,100 |
| [Imponte](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Imponte) | [Phoenix](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Phoenix) | $2,000 |
| [Western](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Western_Motorcycle_Company) | [Daemon](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Daemon) | $2,000 |
| [Weeny](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Weeny) | [Issi](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Issi) | $1,800 |
| [BF](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/BF) | [Injection](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Injection) | $1,600 |
| [Bravado](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Bravado) | [Youga](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Youga) | $1,600 |
| [Dinka](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Dinka) | [Blista](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Blista) | $1,600 |
| [Karin](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Karin) | [Intruder](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Intruder) | $1,600 |
| [Western](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Western_Motorcycle_Company) | [Bagger](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Bagger) | $1,600 |
| [Albany](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Albany) | [Washington](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Washington) | $1,500 |
| [Bravado](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Bravado) | [Duneloader](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Duneloader) | $1,500 |
| [Declasse](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Declasse) | [Sabre Turbo](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Sabre_Turbo) | $1,500 |
| [Vapid](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Vapid) | [Speedo](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Speedo) | $1,500 |
| [Bravado](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Bravado) | [Rumpo](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Rumpo) | $1,300 |
| [Declasse](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Declasse) | [Asea](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Asea) | $1,200 |
| [Karin](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Karin) | [Sultan](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Sultan) | $1,200 |
| [Principe](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Principe) | [Nemesis](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Nemesis) | $1,200 |
| [Vapid](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Vapid) | [Peyote](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Peyote) | $1,200 |
| [Declasse](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Declasse) | [Premier](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Premier) | $1,000 |
| [Imponte](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Imponte) | [Ruiner](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Ruiner) | $1,000 |
| [Pegassi](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Pegassi) | [Ruffian](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Ruffian) | $1,000 |
| [Vapid](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Vapid) | [Stanier](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Stanier) | $1,000 |
| [Zirconium](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Zirconium) | [Stratum](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Stratum) | $1,000 |
| [Albany](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Albany) | [Primo](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Primo) | $900 |
| [Cheval](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Cheval) | [Picador](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Picador) | $900 |
| [Declasse](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Declasse) | [Rancher XL](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Rancher_XL) | $900 |
| [Karin](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Karin) | [Futo](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Futo) | $900 |
| [Shitzu](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Shitzu) | [PCJ-600](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/PCJ-600) | $900 |
| [Shitzu](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Shitzu) | [Vader](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Vader) | $900 |
| [Vulcar](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Vulcar) | [Ingot](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Ingot) | $900 |
| [Nagasaki](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Nagasaki) | [Blazer](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Blazer) | $800 |
| [Albany](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Albany) | [Emperor](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Emperor) | $800 |
| [Albany](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Albany) | [Manana](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Manana) | $800 |
| [Dundreary](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Dundreary) | [Regina](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Regina) | $800 |
| [Karin](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Karin) | [Rebel](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Rebel) | $700 |
| [Maibatsu](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Maibatsu) | [Sanchez](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Sanchez) | $700 |
| [BF](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/BF) | [Surfer](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Surfer) | $500 |
| [Declasse](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Declasse) | [Voodoo](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Voodoo) | $500 |
| [Pegassi](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Pegassi) | [Faggio](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Faggio) | $500 |

Answer (score 0):

Übermacht oracle $8000 I always find a lot of these look around Michaels area and you'll see plenty  if you want you can get a nissan skyline for free from the internet ingame it is fast so check it out. Also the lampadati felon/gt $9000/$9500 it is quite hard to find and the same with the gallivanter baller which goes for $9000 (SUV)

Comment: Welcome to [gaming.se](http://gaming.stackexchange.com), and thank you for your answer. However, it isn't terribly well written as is -- could you perhaps elaborate on it a bit further?

Answer (score 0):

Just realized I answered this on a duplicate.. adding the answer here as I think it may be the most complete:

From a community created [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AvMnvlv4JzeKdGRVQlVHVUlRY2VoZGQtaFBGYW1HVlE&usp=sharing#gid=0), these seem to be your best options:

```
Lampadi Felon GT      | $ 9 500,00
Lampadati Felon       | $ 9 000,00
Gallivanter Baller    | $ 9 000,00
Obey Rocoto           | $ 8 500,00
Ocelot F620           | $ 8 000,00
Ubermacht Oracle      | $ 8 000,00
Benefactor Dubsta     | $ 7 000,00
Albany Cavalclade     | $ 7 000,00
Ubermacht Zion        | $ 6 500,00
Ubermacht Zion Cabrio | $ 6 500,00
Benefactor Schafter   | $ 6 500,00
Ocelot Jackal         | $ 6 000,00
Benefactor Serrano    | $ 6 000,00
Ubermacht Sentinel XS | $ 6 000,00
Ubermacht Sentinel    | $ 6 000,00
Dundreary Landstalker | $ 5 800,00
Fathom FQ 2           | $ 5 000,00
Mammoth Patriot       | $ 5 000,00
```

Note that having the windows smashed reduces the sell price by $70, and further damages reduces the price even more.  See the linked spreadsheet for the sell prices of more cars.

Taken from [reddit](http://ct.reddit.com/r/GrandTheftAutoV/comments/1nn7xr/gtao_los_santos_customs_car_sell_price_spreadsheet/).