# GTA V online stolen vehicles

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I'm curious about cars that you can steal and sell for the most money in GTA Online.

I know there's a chance that modded Sentinel XS can spawn after midngiht till morning near Tequi-la-la which can be sold around 14k-18k and modded Sandkings spawns near the LS Customs in Sandy Shores, sell price same as Sentinel XS. But are there vehicles that can be sold for more?

Comment: If you have a Dubsta2, you can spawn in more Dubsta2s which sell for more than $10k. I've also seen ruiners and dominators (and potentially more, I'm still testing) spawn while using the Dubsta2 spawn method, and those sell for $10k+ each as well. There's also a Sandking XL that may spawn in Blaine county, yet I've never been able to get those to spawn.

Comment: There are far more productive ways to earn GTA$... just sayin'

Comment: yes I know, i was just curious about vehicles

Answer (score 1):

These appear to be the highest selling cars

[image: 1]]

[according to this link](https://gtacentral.com/gta-5/online-stolen-car-prices/) and verified by [this link](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Los_Santos_Customs/Vehicle_Prices) and [this, potentially duplicate, question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/133145/which-stolen-cars-can-you-bring-to-ls-customs-and-what-are-their-sell-prices-in).

Comment: yes i know these, but sometimes you can find some custom modified or tuned cars around the map that you can sell for more